Ignore Doxygen trailing comments within function
I am using ST's RFAL library which has many comments on the definitions that are trailing the value.
Example:
#define RFAL_ANALOG_CONFIG_LUT_SIZE                 (87U)     /*!< Maximum number of Configuration IDs in the Loop Up Table     */
#define RFAL_ANALOG_CONFIG_LUT_NOT_FOUND            (0xFFU)   /*!< Index value indicating no Configuration IDs found            */

#define RFAL_ANALOG_CONFIG_TBL_SIZE                 (1024U)   /*!< Maximum number of Register-Mask-Value in the Setting List    */

I am using Doxygen for code commentary and have found that this is resulting in gross behavior when referencing definitions within my code.

All of the comments with "<" preceding the line are due to be using one of RFAL's definitions within this function.
Is there any way I can ignore inner function commentary? I don't intend to ever comment my code where I expect Doxygen to parse the inside of a function. But I still want the definition comment when I look at one of RFAL's definitions in Doxygen.

Have you tried to set HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS to YES in the Doxyfile? Other than that, have a look at the section "Configuration options related to the preprocessor". But it would be better if you could show us the piece of code (with comments and the macro usage) and the preprocessor macro definition.

I agree with @ErdalKüçük that a small complete example is needed. Also which version of doxygen are you using (might make a difference)?

@ErdalKüçük I did not have that set. That provided the desired affect. Thanks so much!

"Is there any way I can ignore inner function commentary?"
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS

If the HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS tag is set to YES, Doxygen will hide any documentation blocks found inside the body of a function. If set to NO, these blocks will be appended to the function's detailed documentation block.
The default value is: NO.

